how do i connect to a remote host internal server with sudo access using Ansible?
I am currently working on a Automation Project , I am using Ansible to Automate. Now in my particular scenario , I am supposed to establish ssh to one of the internal server on the remote host in order to run the desired commands. Let's understand the remote server architecture to understand the situation.
Here is the remote server architecture

ansible -> remote server host -> nonroot user access defined in the inventory
ansible -> perform/run: "sudo su -" -> with this I will be connected to host with root user.
ansible -> root@host# -- ssh adm@1.1.1.1 -> basically am connecting to an internal host, user: adm
ansible -> adm@1.1.1.1# "sudo  su -" -> this step is required to gain root access of internal server.


So basically the expected SSH connection flow is like this :  ansible--root@host--adm@1.1.1.1---root@1.1.1.1
Only if i have access to: root@1.1.1.1# , I will be able to run desired linux commands.
I attempted the exact flow in my playbook, but eventually it get stucks asking for password. Now except for the remote host nonroot user access, no password is required along the way.
Now because the "permitRootLogin: no" in the sshd_config on the remote server, I cannot remotely fire the command from ansible server , with root user(ansible -> ssh root@1.1.1.1 'desired linux commands')
Any suggestion on how we can achieve this, would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the piece of Code , that I have been attempting:
---
- name: Connect to remote host and execute commands on internal server
  hosts: remote_host
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure we can connect to the remote host
      ping:

    - name: SSH into internal server and run Ansible role as root
      shell: |
        ssh -tt adm@1.1.1.1 << 'EOF'
        sudo su -
        ansible-playbook /path/to/run_role.yml
        EOF
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash

I tried the below solution but not working , gets stuck ..


name: Connect to remote host and execute commands on internal server
hosts: remote_host
become: yes
become_user: root
tasks:

name: Ensure we can connect to the remote host
ping:

name: SSH into internal server and run Ansible role as root
shell: |
ssh -tt adm@1.1.1.1 << 'EOF'
sudo su -
ansible-playbook /path/to/run_role.yml
EOF
args:
executable: /bin/bash




